# How would I go about fixing this timer in After Effects?

Tags: javascript, after-effects

I'm attempting to make a timer for my video in AE, but when the timer gets to 10 minutes, an extra 0 is added to the front of the counter.

[image]

Any idea on how I can fix this?

```js
sek = Math.floor(time%60);
min = Math.floor(time/60);



if(sek<10)
{
    "0" + min +":0" + sek;
}
else
{
    "0" + min +":" + sek;
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `time`?

Comment: What is your image supposed to show? I hardly couldn't recognize anything, apart from that it does show some text/code, which could as well be shown inline within the question. Please replace the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four scenarios you should watch out for as represented below. The issue has a simple fix, trying this out should work

```js
sek = Math.floor(time%60);
min = Math.floor(time/60);

if(min<10 && sek<10)
{
    "0" + min +":0" + sek;
}
else if(min<10 && sek>=10)
{
   "0" + min +":" + sek;
}
else if(min>=10 && sek<10)
{
    min + ":0" + sek;
}
else if (min>=10 && sek>=10)
{
    min +":" + sek;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!